# Cannot run mysql after moving data (Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist)

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, winamp

I come here from this [topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/291126/mysql-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-host-doe)

Where user has exactly the same problem.

I have installed Winamp (Apache+Mysql). I moved my /data subfolders (backup) to mysql/data (installed folder). I originally had error that my port is in use, so I changed to 3307. The cause for this error could be freeze of mysqld-nt (not closed, stayed in memory)

- port is 3307
- data folder is in my.ini is set correctly
- client run results in close because mysql-nt doesnt run
- mysqld-nt Freezes console.
- cannot run console
- mysqld-nt is closed (manually)

I am Windows user. My Mysql is part of Wamp server and has no any mysql_install_db
 in bin folder. I don't use linux so I cannot use linux commands. Also I cannot run client bevazse server connection is not established so cannot type the command for client.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that port 3306 is in use could be a clue that your old Mysql server process is still running and hogging the port.
Because it's windows, you may have to reboot.

Your data backup might have been corrupted, or not copied over correctly.

Comment: I restarted. No daemon in memory. Port is free. 120110 21:32:09  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43655
120110 21:32:09 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Comment: WAMP installed to foler: c:\wampserver but log is in c:\wampserver\wamp\logs ... c:\wampserver\wamp\ is the old location of the previous server (same version BTW). Now I dont know how it is possible that (?) this mysql is running (?) ,,, I installed to c:\wampserver\

Comment: Also I found my.ini is saved in the same (incorrect) location like log file.

Comment: SOLVED. I CANT POST HERE MY ANSWER. NO RIGHTS